# creating a dataframe with main columns stacked on top of each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to stack the open and close prices onto of each other to create a longer series. There should be three columns, each column the name of the stock

I have tried using `df.stack()` but it stacks the stock names onto of each other

```
df=data[['Open', 'Close']]
df

                            Open                   Close
            ABBV    ABMD    ABT     ABBV    ABMD    ABT
Date                        
2013-12-31  52.99   27.47   38.38   52.81   26.74   38.33
2014-01-02  52.12   26.66   38.09   51.98   26.85   38.23
2014-01-03  52.25   26.84   38.37   52.30   27.06   38.64
2014-01-06  52.70   27.23   39.19   50.39   27.30   39.15
```

Comment: What's the actual goal here?

Comment: To create a longer series of prices, so to put the open above the closing prices for each stock.

Comment: Yes but why? What is your end goal.

Comment: to do analysis on stock prices, I can get more granular if I have a more detailed series.

Comment: Are you just trying to compute open to close return using `pct_change` or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `stack` stacks the last index level, which contains the stock's names in your case. Specify a different level:

```
df = df.stack(level=0)

df.index.names = ['Date', 'Type']
df = df.reset_index().sort_values(['Date', 'Type'], ascending=[True, False])
```

Result:

```
         Date   Type   ABBV   ABMD    ABT
1  2013-12-31   Open  52.99  27.47  38.38
0  2013-12-31  Close  52.81  26.74  38.33
3  2014-01-02   Open  52.12  26.66  38.09
2  2014-01-02  Close  51.98  26.85  38.23
5  2014-01-03   Open  52.25  26.84  38.37
4  2014-01-03  Close  52.30  27.06  38.64
7  2014-01-06   Open  52.70  27.23  39.19
6  2014-01-06  Close  50.39  27.30  39.15
```

You can `set_index('Date')` or `reset_index(drop=True)` to reset the left-most index column.

Comment: The open should be before the close though?

Comment: The open and close rows need to be swapped around. How do I do this please.

Comment: They are ordered alphabetically. The simplest way is just to sort the `Type` column in reverse alphabetical order. See my edited answer.

Comment: Mate you are a champion! Thanks so much for your help!